# Select number of count that is below 10 before | in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dynamic string

```
'c:\-231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-19.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-1.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-9.58|';
```

As you can see number just before '|' that is 19.58,1.58,9.58  etc  in above string.

I want to get count how many number is below 10 out of total count.
Like in the example above, count 2 out of 3.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Normalise your string before it gets anywhere near SQL Server, then you can easily `COUNT` the number of rows `WHERE ColumnName < 10`.

Comment: Also what does `Gb-19.58` represent? `Gb` `19.58`? `Gb-` `19.58`? `Gb` `-19.58`? Based on the first value in your string (`-231.53`), I'd guess `Gb` `-19.58`, so all the values have a value less than `10`.

Comment: nothing I just want to focus on number before '|' .

Comment: is the number before "|" always follows a "-" or is it just a coincidence

Comment: there will always  number before "|" and rest can vary.

Comment: While this is possible to solve with an RDBMS, this doesn't seem to be a task for  a database system. You decided to store the string in its current form, so the DBMS shall be oblivious to its structure. Then don't do that in the DBMS. Just read the string and use some programming language to parse it, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to give the below a try ?

I've split the operations into CTE's to make it understandable ...

```
DECLARE @input_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'c:\-231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-19.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-1.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-9.58|';

with cte_split
  as (SELECT value
        FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input_string, '|')),
     cte_number_start
  as (select PATINDEX('%[^0-9,.]%', REVERSE(value)) - 1 start_of_number,
             value
        from cte_split),
     cte_final
  as (select CONVERT(numeric(18, 10),
                     right(value, case
                                       when start_of_number <= 0 then len(value)
                                       else start_of_number end)) number
        from cte_number_start
       where ISNUMERIC(right(value, case
                                         when start_of_number <= 0 then len(value)
                                         else start_of_number end)) = 1)
select COUNT(case
                  when number < 10 then 1
                  else null end) below_ten,
       COUNT(number) total
  from cte_final
```

For prior to sql server version 16 that does not have the STRING_SPLIT function. I did not have time for complete error handling, so you have to make sure that the string always ends with a "|", else the last split will be missed. I've borrowed the logic for splitting string from here - https://www.b1prosuite.com/docs/whp/3261/en/mssql-string-split-for-older-sql-server-versions.html )

```
DECLARE @input_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'c:\-231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-19.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-1.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-9.58|';

with cte_split
  as (select value = SUBSTRING(@input_string, 1, CHARINDEX('|', @input_string) - 1),
             left_over = SUBSTRING(
                             @input_string,
                             CHARINDEX('|', @input_string) + 1,
                             LEN(@input_string) - CHARINDEX('|', @input_string))
      union all
      select value = SUBSTRING(left_over, 1, CHARINDEX('|', left_over) - 1),
             left_over = SUBSTRING(left_over, CHARINDEX('|', left_over) + 1, LEN(left_over) - CHARINDEX('|', left_over))
        from cte_split
       where CHARINDEX('|', left_over) > 0),
     cte_number_start
  as (select PATINDEX('%[^0-9,.]%', REVERSE(value)) - 1 start_of_number,
             value
        from cte_split),
     cte_final
  as (select CONVERT(numeric(18, 10),
                     right(value, case
                                       when start_of_number <= 0 then len(value)
                                       else start_of_number end)) number
        from cte_number_start
       where ISNUMERIC(right(value, case
                                         when start_of_number <= 0 then len(value)
                                         else start_of_number end)) = 1)
select COUNT(case
                  when number < 10 then 1
                  else null end) below_ten,
       COUNT(number) total
  from cte_final
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT  is not working in sql

Comment: what is the version of your sql server ? Asking because STRING_SPLIT function is available only from sql server 2016. If yours is an earlier version, we'll have do a different approach

Comment: sql server 15.0

Comment: I've updated the answer by adding a working for before sql server 16. Let me know if this helps . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In sql you first creates a temporary table to hold the individual numbers from the input string. It uses the STRING_SPLIT function to split the input string by '|' and inserts the numbers into the temporary table. Then, it counts the numbers below 10 using a SELECT statement and finally cleans up the temporary table.

The result of the query will be the count of numbers below 10.

`DECLARE @input_string NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'c:\-231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-19.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-1.58|231.53 Gb-36.08 Gb-9.58|';

-- Create a temporary table to hold the individual numbers
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Number DECIMAL(18, 2));

-- Split the input string by '|', and insert the numbers into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT CAST(value AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@input_string, '|');

-- Count the numbers below 10
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountBelow10
FROM #TempTable
WHERE Number < 10;

-- Clean up the temporary table
DROP TABLE #TempTable;`

If STRING_SPLIT is not working, You can do it:

```html
-- Create a table variable to hold the individual numbers
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Number DECIMAL(18, 2));

-- Variables for parsing
DECLARE @start INT = 1, @end INT, @delimiter CHAR(1) = '|';
SET @input_string = @input_string + @delimiter;

-- Loop to split the input string and insert the numbers into the table variable
WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input_string, @start) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input_string, @start);
    INSERT INTO @TempTable (Number)
    VALUES (CAST(SUBSTRING(@input_string, @start, @end - @start) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)));
    SET @start = @end + 1;
END

-- Count the numbers below 10
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountBelow10
FROM @TempTable
WHERE Number < 10;
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is not working in sql

Comment: I edit the answer without STRING_SPLIT